# Reshaping\Stacking Multiple Variables in R, Triads to Dyads

Tags: r, reshape

I have data describing an interaction of an individual (player 1) with two others (player 2 and player 3). Each row describes a unique combination of players, but I would like to analyze the player 1 to player 2 and player 1 to player 3 dyads separately. To accomplish this I am envisioning some sort of stacking where I can melt descriptive variables for players two and three while maintaining the data for player 1 in each row. Making matters more complicated I have multiple descriptive variables for each individual.

Here is a small bit of data to work with (I actually have far more descriptive variables for players 2 and 3 which I would like to stack/melt):

```
    p1_id <- c(1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1021, 1032, 1032, 1032, 1032, 1032, 1032)
    p1_age <- c(53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45)
    p2_id <- c(14372, 15022,  9072, 15052, 2161, 18381, 15032, 14451, 16322, 11142, 8182,  1131, 7092, 4071, 16191, 18142, 4222, 11052, 2202, 16151)
    p2_money <- c(4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 0, 0, 10, 0, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6)
    p2_age <- c(50, 33, 56, 23, 29, 26, 28, 34, 20, 41, 34, 45, 23, 35, 25, 30, 40, 41, 45, 28)
    p3_id <- c(5151, 16181, 5182, 18462, 7231, 14372, 3052, 14532, 4152, 15012, 19212, 9062, 9032, 18351, 14461, 16291, 17102, 10102, 7051, 16282)
    p3_money <- c(4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 10, 10, 0, 10, 6, 6, 4, 6, 4)
    p3_age <- c(30, 29, 22, 22, 43, 50, 23, 32, 31, 46, 36, 36, 21, 27, 49, 38, 40, 48, 26, 32)
    df <- data.frame(p1_id, p1_age, p2_id, p2_money, p2_age, p3_id, p3_money, p3_age)
```

The dataframe:

```
     p1_id p1_age p2_id p2_money p2_age p3_id p3_money p3_age
     1   1021     53 14372        4     50  5151        4     30
     2   1021     53 15022        2     33 16181        2     29
     3   1021     53  9072        2     56  5182        2     22
     4   1021     53 15052        2     23 18462        2     22
     5   1021     53  2161        2     29  7231        2     43
     6   1021     53 18381        2     26 14372        2     50
     7   1021     53 15032        2     28  3052        2     23
     8   1021     53 14451        2     34 14532        2     32
     9   1021     53 16322        2     20  4152        2     31
     10  1021     53 11142        2     41 15012        2     46
     11  1021     53  8182       10     34 19212        0     36
     12  1021     53  1131        0     45  9062       10     36
     13  1021     53  7092        0     23  9032       10     21
     14  1021     53  4071       10     35 18351        0     27
     15  1032     53 16191        0     25 14461       10     49
     16  1032     45 18142        6     30 16291        6     38
     17  1032     45  4222        6     40 17102        6     40
     18  1032     45 11052        4     41 10102        4     48
     19  1032     45  2202        6     45  7051        6     26
     20  1032     45 16151        6     28 16282        4     32
```

In case my description above was too confusing, here is how I would like the reshaped data to look:

```
     row p1_id p1_age p23_id p23_money p23_age 
     1   1021     53 14372        4     50  
     2   1021     53 15022        2     33 
     3   1021     53  9072        2     56  
     4   1021     53 15052        2     23 
     5   1021     53  2161        2     29  
     6   1021     53 18381        2     26 
     7   1021     53 15032        2     28 
     8   1021     53 14451        2     34
     9   1021     53 16322        2     20
     10  1021     53 11142        2     41 
     11  1021     53  8182       10     34 
     12  1021     53  1131        0     45  
     13  1021     53  7092        0     23  
     14  1021     53  4071       10     35 
     15  1032     53 16191        0     25 
     16  1032     45 18142        6     30 
     17  1032     45  4222        6     40 
     18  1032     45 11052        4     41 
     19  1032     45  2202        6     45  
     20  1032     45 16151        6     28 
     21  1021     53  5151        4     30  
     22  1021     53 16181        2     29
     23  1021     53  5182        2     22
     24  1021     53 18462        2     22
     25  1021     53  7231        2     43 
     26  1021     53 14372        2     50
     27  1021     53  3052        2     23 
     28  1021     53 14532        2     32 
     28  1021     53  4152        2     31
     30  1021     53 19212        0     36
     31  1021     53  9062       10     36 
     32  1021     53  9032       10     21 
     33  1021     53 18351        0     27
     34  1032     53 16191        0     25
     35  1032     53 14461       10     49
     36  1032     53 16291        6     38
     37  1032     53 17102        6     40 
     38  1032     53 10102        4     48 
     39  1032     53  7051        6     26 
     40  1032     53 16282        4     32
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you try to do ? What type of comparisons you try to achieve, I don't think that putting all the rows together will help for further analysis. aLso it is normal that p1 don't have money variable?

Comment: How did either of these answers work out for you? If you're happy with any of them, do be sure to up-vote them; if one of them solves your problem or helps you to do so, consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the big check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I am actually trying them out currently. I'll be sure to vote up one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty easily done if you modify your column names as follows:

```
names(df) <- gsub("(.*)_(.*)", "\\2\\.\\1", names(df))
names(df)
# [1] "id.p1"    "age.p1"   "id.p2"    "money.p2" 
# [5] "age.p2"   "id.p3"    "money.p3" "age.p3"
```

Next, use the "row.names" of your `data.frame` as your "idvar" in base R `reshape()`.

```
reshape(df, direction = "long", idvar = "row.names",
        timevar = "person", varying = 3:8)
#       id.p1 age.p1 person    id money age row.names
# 1.p2   1021     53     p2 14372     4  50         1
# 2.p2   1021     53     p2 15022     2  33         2
# 3.p2   1021     53     p2  9072     2  56         3
# 4.p2   1021     53     p2 15052     2  23         4
# 5.p2   1021     53     p2  2161     2  29         5
# 6.p2   1021     53     p2 18381     2  26         6
# 7.p2   1021     53     p2 15032     2  28         7
# 8.p2   1021     53     p2 14451     2  34         8
# 9.p2   1021     53     p2 16322     2  20         9
# 10.p2  1021     53     p2 11142     2  41        10
# 11.p2  1021     53     p2  8182    10  34        11
# 12.p2  1021     53     p2  1131     0  45        12
# 13.p2  1021     53     p2  7092     0  23        13
# 14.p2  1021     53     p2  4071    10  35        14
# 15.p2  1032     53     p2 16191     0  25        15
# 16.p2  1032     45     p2 18142     6  30        16
# 17.p2  1032     45     p2  4222     6  40        17
# 18.p2  1032     45     p2 11052     4  41        18
# 19.p2  1032     45     p2  2202     6  45        19
# 20.p2  1032     45     p2 16151     6  28        20
# 1.p3   1021     53     p3  5151     4  30         1
# 2.p3   1021     53     p3 16181     2  29         2
# 3.p3   1021     53     p3  5182     2  22         3
# 4.p3   1021     53     p3 18462     2  22         4
# 5.p3   1021     53     p3  7231     2  43         5
# 6.p3   1021     53     p3 14372     2  50         6
# 7.p3   1021     53     p3  3052     2  23         7
# 8.p3   1021     53     p3 14532     2  32         8
# 9.p3   1021     53     p3  4152     2  31         9
# 10.p3  1021     53     p3 15012     2  46        10
# 11.p3  1021     53     p3 19212     0  36        11
# 12.p3  1021     53     p3  9062    10  36        12
# 13.p3  1021     53     p3  9032    10  21        13
# 14.p3  1021     53     p3 18351     0  27        14
# 15.p3  1032     53     p3 14461    10  49        15
# 16.p3  1032     45     p3 16291     6  38        16
# 17.p3  1032     45     p3 17102     6  40        17
# 18.p3  1032     45     p3 10102     4  48        18
# 19.p3  1032     45     p3  7051     6  26        19
# 20.p3  1032     45     p3 16282     4  32        20
```

#### Update: Using `dcast()` from "reshape2"

Hopefully someone more well-versed in the "reshape2" package (or perhaps with "plyr") would  be able to come up with a more concise solution than the one below. This solution involves:

1. A dummy "id" column.
2. "Melting" the dataset.
3. Using `colsplit()` (from "reshape2") to generate a couple of new columns.
4. Using `dcast()` to get to the desired form.

Here's what it looks like:

```
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)
df2 <- melt(df, id.vars=c("id", "p1_id", "p1_age"))
df2 <- cbind(df2[-4], 
             colsplit(df2$variable, "_", c("person", "var")))
head(df2)
out <- dcast(df2, id + p1_id + p1_age + person ~ var)
list(head(out), tail(out))
# [[1]]
#   id p1_id p1_age person age    id money
# 1  1  1021     53     p2  50 14372     4
# 2  1  1021     53     p3  30  5151     4
# 3  2  1021     53     p2  33 15022     2
# 4  2  1021     53     p3  29 16181     2
# 5  3  1021     53     p2  56  9072     2
# 6  3  1021     53     p3  22  5182     2
# 
# [[2]]
#    id p1_id p1_age person age    id money
# 35 18  1032     45     p2  41 11052     4
# 36 18  1032     45     p3  48 10102     4
# 37 19  1032     45     p2  45  2202     6
# 38 19  1032     45     p3  26  7051     6
# 39 20  1032     45     p2  28 16151     6
# 40 20  1032     45     p3  32 16282     4
```

So, basically, whatever approach you take, it looks like you'll have to do some pre-processing of your `data.frame` to get it in a format more friendly for such transformations.

Comment: Sorry for the edits. Wasn't paying attention to which attempt I was copying and pasting. I guess the moral of these edits is "Don't answer questions on SO while you are making your lunch."

Comment: Might I suggest to use sep='_' to avoid renaming step?

Comment: @agstudy, you might, but you'd still need to do some manipulation because of how `reshape()` works. Notice that in the renaming step, I'm reversing what is to be considered the "time" and what is considered to be the "variable". If you come up with a cool solution using `sep = "_"`, do share!

Comment: oops..good catch!. I see it just now! +1(clever inversion) ..I think I need a double coffee an reread the reshape help!

Comment: @agstudy, Trust me, even a quadruple coffee won't help. I think the `reshape()` help page could benefit from a few more examples demonstrating how the different arguments influence the output.

Comment: I trust you @AnandaMahto that's why my first reflex is to use **plyr/reshape2** for such manipulations.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22258/discussion-between-ananda-mahto-and-agstudy)

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the most efficient way, but I think it does what you want.

```
df <- data.frame(p1_id, p1_age, p2_id, p2_money, p2_age, p3_id, p3_money, p3_age)

player2 <- df[,names(df) %in% c('p1_id','p1_age','p2_id','p2_money','p2_age')]
colnames(player2) <- c('p1_id', 'p1_age', 'p23_id', 'p23_money', 'p23_age')

player3 <- df[,names(df) %in% c('p1_id','p1_age','p3_id','p3_money','p3_age')]
colnames(player3) <- c('p1_id', 'p1_age', 'p23_id', 'p23_money', 'p23_age')

df2 <- rbind(player2, player3)
df2
```

Except why does the age of 1032 change in your posted data set?  Player 1032 is age 45 in one data set and 53 in another.  So I am not understanding something and perhaps my answer is not doing what you want.

Actually Player 1032 is age 53 in one line of the original data set and age 45 in five lines.  A total of 6 rows.

In your reshaped data set Player 1032 is age 53 in eight lines and age 45 in five lines.  A total of 13 rows.

Is this a typographic error?  If not, my answer is incorrect.

EDIT:

Assuming my answer above is correct and assuming the columns are always ordered by player and then attribute, the following code will work for any number of player attributes and only requires changing `n.player1` and the column names of `df2`.

```
df <- data.frame(p1_id, p1_age, p2_id, p2_money, p2_age, p3_id, p3_money, p3_age)

n.player1 <- 2

player2 <- df[,1:(n.player1+((ncol(df)-n.player1)/2))]
colnames(player2) <- paste("X", seq_along(1:ncol(player2)), sep="")

player3 <- df[,c(1:n.player1,(ncol(player2)+1):ncol(df))]
colnames(player3) <- paste("X", seq_along(1:ncol(player3)), sep="")

df2 <- rbind(player2, player3)
colnames(df2) <- c('p1_id', 'p1_age', 'p23_id', 'p23_money', 'p23_age')
df2
```